# How to use seccomp filter with ebpf?

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf, seccomp

I'm looking for an example of  eBPF to write a seccomp filter, but I can't find none. Could someone tell me if is possible to use eBPF to write seccomp filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seccomp does not work with eBPF at the moment (only cBPF).

There was [a discussion](https://lwn.net/Articles/796328/) not long ago on that topic on the Linux networking mailing list. The eBPF maintainer is against adding eBPF support to seccomp.

Comment: "the goal of opening up BPF to unprivileged users has been abandoned as unachievable, and that further work in that direction will not be accepted by the BPF maintainer" , still It's possible to attach an ebpf socket filter to an udp socket without priviliges. Does that statement mean that it won't be possible in the future?

Comment: Very unlikely, that would break user API. Linux community has a strong policy against breaking existing user applications.

Comment: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/containers/2018-February/038476.html is this patch merged  in some kernel? How can I check it? In my kernels source code I don't have the seccomp examples.

Comment: To search for it you could try to grep it from the git log (e.g. `git log --oneline | grep "eBPF Seccomp filters"`). It's BPF so it would probably be added through bpf-next tree (but not 100% sure because it also touches security stuff). But in practice you can save yourself the trouble: I can tell you it has not been merged as of today. (Full thread [here](https://lore.kernel.org/netdev/20180226072651.GA27045@ircssh-2.c.rugged-nimbus-611.internal/) by the way).

Answer (score 2):

[Kernel Runtime Security Instrumentation (KRSI)](https://lwn.net/Articles/798157/) was designed for this. [It's already been merged into the kernel.](https://twitter.com/mjg59/status/1245454750323113984)

Comment: Unfortunately KRSI requires root, but seccomp does not.